# Cannot create project in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I have installed Visual Studio Community 2015. When I want to create any project it gives this error:

[image]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>

Please guide me to what should I do.

Comment: what kind of project are you trying to create? .androidproj files are most commonly associated with the AndroidStudio IDE, rather than VS.

Comment: .androidproj is the one of project options in visual studio. As this link we can develop android app in visual studio https://www.visualstudio.com/vs-2015-product-editions

Comment: The .androidproj extension does seem really weird.  Although, this might be made from a C++ and/or Xamarin cross platform project template that I'm not aware of.